# Symfony doctrine queries with joins performance

Tags: performance, symfony, doctrine

I run next query with join -

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('products')->select('products')
->leftJoin('products.sizes', 'sizes')->addselect('sizes');
```

and all products sizes selected in one query. Without `->addselect('sizes')` i has over 50 queries. But total aplication time is less then in first example. I did something wrong in first example?

Comment: If you don't add `addselect('sizes')` doctrine will create proxies for `sizes`, and if you iterate over `sizes` later and access it's members, doctrine will do  a query for each `size`. But I cannot explain why the app is faster. Doctrine cache?

Answer (score 0):

If you do *addSelect*, Doctrine will perform only one query that will fetch all the information you need and hydrate it in one object. If then you do a

```
foreach($products as $product){
  foreach($product->getSizes() as $size(){
     echo $size->getStuff();
  }
}
```

Doctrine will not do any additional query.
If you omit the *addSelect*, Doctrine will perform a query for each size of your products. Now, you have to challenge your application to see what is the best solution.
On some solution one big query/hydration performs better than dozen of small queries. Each application will respond differently.